# How can I make gdb automatically attach to a program name on a remote machine?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I'm trying to setup my gdbinit to make gdb automatically attach to a certain program on a remote machine.

My script is something like:

```
define hook-run
  target extended-remote | ssh -T remotemachine gdbserver --multi -
  attach $pid
  ... <additional complicated stuff here>
end
```

My problem, of course, is that I'm missing $pid. I can find it by running `ssh remotemachine ps | grep myprogram`, but I'm not sure how to run that from within the gdb script and assign it into that `$pid` variable. How can I do that? I'm guessing I'm going to need some Python here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can find it by running `ssh remotemachine ps | grep myprogram`

I believe your choices are

1. use Python, or
2. escape to shell

For (2) you can use something like:

```
define hook-run
  shell gen-remote-run.sh > .remote-cmd.gdb
  source .remote-cmd.gdb
end
```

and put all the "magic" of figuring out remote PID into `gen-remote-run.sh`

Comment: Thanks, I made my script generate a file containing `attach <number>` where `<number>` is already the calculated PID, and it worked.